# Incompatibility between NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 and Asus M5A97

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure

Recently I've bought an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 graphics card to replace GT 640 in my machine. For a week it worked perfectly, both in Windows and GNU/Linux (games and GPGPU). But suddenly (no updates, changes to other hardware components) it began to distort image - it changes to reddish-pink hue with noise. In GNU/Linux it starts at X start, when `nvidia-modeset` module is loaded. In Windows it starts after some several seconds after 3D display is activated, though in some games such distortion lasts for about 10 seconds before the screen goes blank and rendering continues for some other 30 seconds. The problem persists both with cold and warm card.

What I've already tried to fix this problem:

- updating motherboard BIOS firmware to the latest version (2603) did not change the symptoms;
- older GPU works fine (both OSes, all usage scenarious) after replacing back;
- bringing card for RMA: running it on a test stand showed no signs of this problem whatsoever during about 40 minutes of stress-testing;
- running memtest86+ did not show any errors;
- disabling ECC did not help;
- switching PSU 8-pin connectors did not help either.

What could be the reason for such strange behaviour? What can be done to fix this incompatibility, or is it a sign of failing hardware?

---

Hardware:

- MB: Asus M5A97 R2.0
- CPU: AMD FX-8350
- PSU: Chieftec A-135 650W backed by UPS
- RAM: 2x Kingston DDR3-1333 8GB with ECC enabled
- GPU (old): Zotac GT640 Zone Edition 2GB 128bit DDR3
- GPU (new): Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1060 6GB GV-N1060D5-6GD

Software:

- Windows 7 x64 Home Premium with latest nVidia drivers (376.33)
- Debian GNU/Linux 8.0 x86_64 with proprietary nVidia drivers from backports (367.57)